# Функция для вычисления среднего значения свойства объекта в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы

Помогите пожалуйста реализовать функцию, которая должна вернуть массив с объектами с вычисленным средним значением values у объектов с одинаковым значением weekNumber

К примеру есть массив

```
const arr1 = [
  {weekNumber: 2, values: 2},
  {weekNumber: 2, values: 4},
  {weekNumber: 4, values: 6},
  {weekNumber: 4, values: 14},
]
```

в результате работы функция должна вернуть такой массив

```
const arr2 = [
  {weekNumber: 2, values: 3},
  {weekNumber: 4, values: 10}
]
```

Comment: Сколько платите?

Comment: Плачу большим человеческим спасибо :) мне бы хотя бы примерный план реализации, а дальше я сам попробую

Comment: Где ваш код? Добавьте в вопрос код которым вы пытались это сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используем `reduce`. Проходимся по каждому элементу массива, проверяем есть ли он в промежуточном массиве `ac`. Если да - добавляем значение и делим на 2, если нет - просто добавляем весь объект.

```js
const arr1 = [
  {weekNumber: 2, values: 2},
  {weekNumber: 2, values: 4},
  {weekNumber: 4, values: 6},
  {weekNumber: 4, values: 14}
];

console.log(
  arr1.reduce((ac, cu) => {
    const i = ac.map(e => e.weekNumber).indexOf(cu.weekNumber);
    if (i === -1) {
      ac.push(cu);
    } else {
      ac[i].values += cu.values;
    }
    return ac;
  }, []).map(e => ({ ...e,
    values: e.values / arr1.filter(j => j.weekNumber === e.weekNumber).length
  }))
);
```

Comment: @InDevX, кстати да, проверить лень было. Сейчас поправлю

Comment: Подгоняете под мой ответ :)

Comment: @AzizUmarov, ну кол-во элементов надо же как-то брать) Но я не смотрел :)

Comment: А деление на 2 чем вам не решение было?

Comment: @AzizUmarov, `((3+6)/2 + 5)/2 !== (3+6+5)/2`

Comment: @AzizUmarov, `/3` вернее, а не на два в другой части

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Можно так получить

```js
const arr1 = [
  {weekNumber: 2, values: 2},
  {weekNumber: 2, values: 4},
  {weekNumber: 4, values: 6},
  {weekNumber: 4, values: 14}
];


let result = arr1
              .reduce((acc, item) => { 
                 acc.filter(item2 => item2.weekNumber == item.weekNumber).length > 0 ? 
                    acc.filter(item2 => item2.weekNumber == item.weekNumber)[0].values.push(item.values) 
                 :  acc.push({weekNumber:item.weekNumber, values:[item.values]}) ; return acc;
               }, [])
              .map(item => ({ 
      weekNumber: item.weekNumber, 
      values: (item.values.reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0)/item.values.length)
      }));

console.log(result);
```

и немного минифициируем

```js
const arr1 = [
  {weekNumber: 2, values: 2},
  {weekNumber: 2, values: 4},
  {weekNumber: 4, values: 6},
  {weekNumber: 4, values: 14}
];


let result = arr1
              .reduce((a, i) => ( 
                 a.filter(i2 => i2.weekNumber == i.weekNumber).length > 0 ? 
                    a.filter(i2 => i2.weekNumber == i.weekNumber)[0].values.push(i.values) 
                 :  a.push({...i, values:[i.values]}), a), [])
              .map(i => ({...i, values: (i.values.reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0)/i.values.length)}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!